# Double linespacing inside equation array

Tags: eqnarray

I want to make the spacing between lines inside an equation array wider because the equations are very near to each other, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Look first at [`eqnarray` vs `align`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196)

Comment: Please add a MWE (i.e. Minimal Working Example, starting with \documentaclass and ending with \end{document}) showing what you got sofar and indicate where you have problems (after studying the advise fro egreg).

Comment: By lines do you mean rows or columns?

Comment: @JohnKormylo rows

Comment: You should also look at \arraystretch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `eqnarray` and other multi-line display math environment, you can indicate how much extra vertical whitespace should be inserted after `\\` by providing an optional argument (yes, `\\` is a macro that can take an optional argument) indicating a valid length, e.g., `1ex` or `[1cm]`.

The following screenshot shows `eqnarray` and `align` environments without any additional vertical spacing between the rows; on the right, the same equations are separated by additional whitespace, in the amount of `1ex`. Select the optimal amount of extra whitespace on a case-by-case basis -- there is no single, uniformly optimal amount.

[image]

Finally, if you compare the outputs of `eqnarray` and `align`, can you tell *why* one should not use `eqnarray` and, instead, use `align`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align' environment
\begin{document}
%% set up two side-by-side 'minipage' environments
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{eqnarray}
1 &=& \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\\
5 &=& \frac{8}{4}+\frac{5}{15}
\end{eqnarray}
\begin{align}
1 &= \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\\
5 &= \frac{8}{4}+\frac{5}{15}
\end{align}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{eqnarray}
1 &=& \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\\[1ex]
5 &=& \frac{8}{4}+\frac{5}{15}
\end{eqnarray}
\begin{align}
1 &= \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\\[1ex]
5 &= \frac{8}{4}+\frac{5}{15}
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```